# Are two metric spaces isometric if they have the same $\varepsilon$-covering numbers for all $\varepsilon>0$?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, packing-and-covering, isometries

Let $(E, d)$ be a metric space. For $\varepsilon>0$, we define two notions of $\varepsilon$-covering number as follows, i.e.,

- $N_\varepsilon^o (E)$ is the smallest number of *open* balls whose radii are $\varepsilon$ that cover $E$.
- $N_\varepsilon^c (E)$ is the smallest number of *closed* balls whose radii are $\varepsilon$ that cover $E$.

Then $N_\varepsilon^o (E)$ is not necessarily equal to $N_\varepsilon^c (E)$, for example, take  $E = \{0, 1\}$ and $\varepsilon=1$. However, if $D$ is a dense subset of $E$, then $N_\varepsilon^c (E) = N_\varepsilon^c (D)$.

Let $(E, d)$ and $(E', d')$ be metric spaces. The spaces $E$ and $E'$ are said to be isometric (denoted by $E \cong E'$) if there is a bijective isometry between them.

I would like to ask if any of below statements is true, i.e.,

> 1. If $N_\varepsilon^o (E) = N_\varepsilon^o (E')$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, then $E \cong E'$.
> 2. If $N_\varepsilon^o (E) = N_\varepsilon^o (E')$ and $N_\varepsilon^c (E) = N_\varepsilon^c (E')$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, then $E \cong E'$.

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: BTW the assertion about dense subsets is not quite correct
because $D$ may be missing the center of a necessary ball.
For example, let $E$ be the interval $[-1,1]$, and $D$ be the dense subset
$[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$.  Then $N_1^c(E) = 1$ but $N_1^c(D) = 2$.

Comment: Stupid answer: there are only continuum many possible functions $\varepsilon\mapsto (N^o(E),N^c(E))$. There are more than continuum many metric spaces up to isometry. So the assignment can't be injective. So the question is more interesting by restricting to compact metric spaces. (Anyway [Noam Elkies's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/442064/14094) addresses this more interesting setting, and even finite metrics paces.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  For $0 < \delta \leq 2$ let $E_\delta$ be the metric space
consisting of three points $A,B,C$ with
$d(A,B) = d(A,C) = 1$ and $d(B,C) = \delta$.
I claim that the $E_\delta$ for $1 \leq \delta \leq 2$ all have
the same covering numbers for all radii $\varepsilon$.
Indeed in every such $E_\delta$
all open $\varepsilon$-balls with $\varepsilon\leq 1$
and all closed $\varepsilon$-balls with $\varepsilon < 1$
contain only their centers, so it takes $3$ such balls to cover the space;
but $E_\delta$ is covered by
a single open $\varepsilon$-ball centered at $A$
once $\varepsilon > 1$,
and also by a single closed $\varepsilon$-ball centered at $A$
once $\varepsilon \geq 1$.  Clearly no two $E_\delta$ with distinct $\delta$ are isometric.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!